# How to set a session attribute in Javascript and then use it in a Spring Controller?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, session

I'm trying read the value of a session attribute in Java that has been set through Javascript before. The attribute gets set correctly as Chrome shows [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQRE5.jpg).
But I can't seem to get this attribute value in the Controller later.
I feel like I'm missing out on something how this whole session thing works.
Because when I debug the code, it just shows me that my **MainController.java** is stored in there.

### My Code

#### main.js

```
function setSessionCounter(count){
    listElementsCounter = count;
    sessionStorage.setItem("listElementsCounter", listElementsCounter);
}
```

#### MainController.java

```
@RestController
@EnableWebMvc
@Scope("session")
public class MainController {

...

@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView showSearchResults(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")SearchParameters sp, ModelMap model, HttpSession session) throws SQLException {

        //Build SQL without the counter
        int elementsCount = (Integer)(session.getAttribute("listElementsCounter"));
        ...
    }
```

I also tried it this way in the Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView showSearchResults(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")SearchParameters sp, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) throws SQLException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        //Build SQL without the counter
        int elementsCount = (Integer)(session.getAttribute("listElementsCounter"));
        ...
    }
```

I would really appreciate if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong (:

Comment: The .js is running in your browser?

Comment: @DaveH Yes it is. the .js is working perfectly fine and sets the value how I want it. But It's not in the `HttpSession` in my Controller.

Comment: There's no automatic connection between session storage on your browser and session storage on the server. If you want to get the information from the browser to the server, you'll need to send it, generally via http PUT or POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is executed on the client side, and no session attributes can be stored.

You can pass information from client to server with, for example, an Ajax call and on the server side (the controller) store the data with the `session.setAttribute` command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I marked it as correct, since I can't mark a comment. DaveH already stated it. I knew that but I didn't consider that there's a session on the client side and a session on the server side. Did exactly the way you mentioned and that works totally fine. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think this will help you in sending ajax request to your spring controller

**In Javascript**

```
function myFunction() {
console.log("clicked on submit button");

var data = {"listElementsCounter":count}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "testurl",
    data:data, 
    success :function(result) {
        //anything you want to do after success

         }  
});
```

}

**In Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/testurl" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void process(@RequestParam("listElementsCounter") Integer count) {

//do whatever you want to do for the count



}
```

Comment: @lakeu-one best answer